# How can I add an effect to know the selected item in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a list and I want to add an effect to the item selected after click. For example when I click to the first item 'Complémentaire forfait' I want to see an effect to know which item is selected from the list.

Here is my HTML. I want to know if I can do what I want with Javascript or jQuery?

```html
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#architect" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  <a class="mdc-list-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Acceuil" style="cursor:pointer;width:350px">
    <i class="architect_aarrow material-icons" style="margin-right:10px">
   add_circle_outline
   </i>Architectes, Ingénieurs et Techniciens
  </a>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="architect" style="margin-left:6px">
  <nav id="icon-with-text-demo" class="mdc-drawer__content mdc-list" style="width:100%">
    <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="CPAIT" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Acceuil" style="cursor:pointer;width:350px">
      Complémentaire forfait
      </a>
    <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="PLACPAIT" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Acceuil" style="cursor:pointer;width:350px">
      Plafonds complémentaire
      </a>
    <a class="mdc-list-item" tauxPlafonds="IDAIT" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Acceuil" style="cursor:pointer;width:350px">
      Invalidité décès
      </a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**My file js :**

```js
$("mdc-list-item").on("click", function () {
 $(this).toggleClass("list-item-clicked");
});
```

**My css :**

```css
.list-item-clicked{
    
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Note that "Accueil" is spelled this way and not "Acceuil" - just saying

Comment: Please update your **code snippet** because result can't see proper. As per my knowledge you can add dynamic class onclick event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to declare a css rule like:

```
.list-item-clicked{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

then add an on click listener to your list items and add or remove the css style to the items when clicked.
With jQuery you can use the toggleClass function.

an implementation could look like this:

```
$(".mdc-list-item").on("click", function(){
      $( this ).toggleClass("list-item-clicked");
})
```

There you add the click listener to all of your items with css class "mdc-list-item" and toggle the class of the specific item.
Toggle class adds the class in parameter if the item does not has it already and removes it when it has it.

```js
$('.mdc-list-item').on("click",function(){
    var isClicked = $(this).hasClass("list-item-clicked"); // am I clicked?
    $('.mdc-list-item').removeClass("list-item-clicked");  // un-click everything
    if(!isClicked)
        $(this).toggleClass("list-item-clicked"); // click me if needed
})
```

```css
.list-item-clicked {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class='mdc-list-item'>First title</a><br/>
<a class='mdc-list-item'>Second title</a><br/>
<a class='mdc-list-item'>Third title</a><br/>
```

Comment: " list-item-clicked " in my case is id of the div that contatin items " architect " or no ??

Comment: no you dont add the class to your divs manually you just let your code as it is right now. Just add the css rule to your css file and the js function to your js file. The function will automaticly add or remove the css class to the taget clicked on.

Comment: I did that i put it excute the function but the css dosn't work

Comment: I changed with border-style but i have the same problem

Comment: :D still my bad try just border ... still a while since the last css

Comment: with border also the same problem

Comment: @KaiLeßmeister I fixed a missing closing parenthesis in your javascript and added a code snippet to your answer

Comment: @Rafalon  also i have the same problem with your code

Comment: @mecab1995 did you just try to run the code snippet and click on one of the titles?

Comment: @Rafalon yes of course dosn't work the problem with the css i think because the function was executed

Comment: @mecab1995 please copy paste your html, css & javascript to your question (preferably in a code snippet) so we can try to see what's wrong with it

Comment: @Rafalon Look again to the question i have added now my js and my css

Comment: @mecab1995 you missed a dot in your first jquery search

Comment: @KaiLeßmeister yes it works but look in the result in the top i added it

Comment: @mecab1995 & KeiLeßmeister I've edited the snippet so only one title can be "selected" at a time

Comment: @Rafalon thank you very munch now it is working correctly